# parseInt'ing Infinity with a radix

Tags: javascript

I was reading twitter when I came across a tweet that said..

```
parseInt(1/0,19); //18
```

Of course, in JS, anything divided by 0 is `Infinity`, but what does the `radix` 19 mean, and why is `Infinity` radix 19 parsed to 18?

Other radix, such as 16, or 10 (default) will yield `"NaN"`, so what's special about the radix 19?

Comment: Seems like anything above 18 does this.

Comment: Now try `parseInt(Infinity.toString() ,19)`, and see that you get the same result, so `Infinity` is irrelevant, it's converted to a string

Comment: @adeneo I forgot the function took strings. This suddenly makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upper-case letters are used in bases above 10, and I is the ninth letter of the alphabet. Thus, it's one less than 19.